# Why DC3 cannot be used as DC2 in suffix array？

Tags: algorithm, suffix-array

I am reading the paper about DC3 to construct suffix array.
I am wondering why DC3 cannot be applied as DC2, so that the calculation will be faster?

Answer (score 1):

For every two integers `$a,b$`, there is an integer `$c\in\{0,1,2}$` such that `$a+c$` and `$b+c$` are both not divisible by `$3$`.

However, for the integers `$a=0,b=1$`, for every integer `$c$`, either `$a+c$` is divisible by `$2$`, or `$b+c$` is divisible by `$2$`.

This difference between divisibility by `$2$` and by `$3$` is what makes it necessary to work with `$3`$ and not with `$2$` in the algorithm. Actually, every integer `$k$` greater or equal to `$3$` works (so it's best to work with `$3$`).

Comment: @kien_coi_1997 the "$" sign is there for a reason and is not part of any formatting. Please don't make such edits in the future, thanks.